# Kineticjs: drag.moving event does't work on latest version. How to upgrade the code?

Tags: javascript, animation, kineticjs

I'm using v3.10.2 of Kineticjs. I'm following the [official demo](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-interactive-ball-physics/)
The problem is at line 48 (where the comment says: "// if dragging and dropping")

In the latest version `.drag` has been removed is replaced wi the `.isDragging()` method.
But what about the `.moving` property? its undefined.

How can I make it work with lastest release of Kineticjs

regards.

Comment: Have you tried `if (ball.isDragging()) {` ?

Comment: yea, didn't work. balll.isDragging() worked in the console. I mean it it returned true when dragged. Let me step through the code once more and get back to you. thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jeykeu/z9FKd/1/
Due to images i think,its not working in the fiddle at all.
Please check the code if its proper?

Comment: @AlexLittlejohn have u found anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to friends who took out time to help.

I just took the code that uses the 3.7.4 version of KineticJS and upgraded it to 3.10.0

and it worked just fine.

please take a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeykeu/DNAYK/)

Here's the [original example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-interactive-ball-physics/#comment-16382)

Happy coding

regards,